# In showing that if $V=X \oplus Y$, then $X \cap Y = \{0\}$, is writing $v=0+v$ and $v=v+0$ for $v \in X \cap Y$ sufficient?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, fake-proofs

$V=X \oplus Y$ if every vector in $V$ can be written uniquely as $v=x+y$ for $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$.

Suppose $V=X \oplus Y$. We want to show $X \cap Y =\{0\}$. Suppose not. Let $v \in X \cap Y$. Then $v=v+0$ where $v \in X$ and $0 \in Y$. Also, $v=0+v$ where $0 \in X$ and $v \in Y$. Thus, $v$ cannot be written uniquely.

**Is this proof sufficient?**

Comment: Is $0\in X\cap Y$? You seem to be assuming it is, which is not valid.

Comment: @TheCount We know it is since $X$ and $Y$ are subspaces.

Comment: Indeed, if $X$ and $Y$ are subspaces, then $X\cap Y=\{\}$ is impossible.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I meant to write $\{0\}$. Edited

Comment: @JonathanZ on second thought, you're entirely right. I'll delete my comment

Comment: This is really a direct proof, so you shouldn’t disguise it as a proof by contradiction. You already know that $\{0\}\subseteq X\cap Y$, because the intersection of subspaces always contains $0$. So now you take something in $X\cap Y$; the fact that $v=v+0=0+v$, but the expression is unique, tells you something about the two expressions, from which you can conclude that....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I'm used to seeing this done by contradiction, like in the question. But your answer is really slick and clever. Some might say it's **too** clever, but I'd give it an upvote if it was an answer.

Comment: @JonathanZ: It's a "fake proof by contradiction".  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112774/proof-by-contradiction-circular-reasoning/112784#112784) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160359/which-one-in-this-problem-is-a-and-which-is-b/160371#160371)

Comment: If you want them to be subspaces, you should call them subspaces. Since you didn't, I didn't assume it.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing missing is specifying that $v \ne 0$, so instead of saying "Let $v \in X \cap Y$" I'd say "Pick a non-zero $v$ in $X \cap Y$". Other than that it's fine.