# Let $K \lhd G$. Then $|G/K| = p$ prime iff $K\le H \le G \Rightarrow H=K $ or $H = G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $K \lhd G$. Prove are equivalent:
>
> a) $K\le H \le G \Rightarrow H=K $ or  $H = G$
>
> b) $|G/K| = p$ with $p$ prime

This is what I know so far about the problem

$K \lhd G$  (stands for '$K$ is normal subgroup of $G$') means that $gKg^{-1}= K, \forall g \in G$

A (left) lateral class of $H \le G$ has the form $xH$  with $x\in G$.

Actually the lateral classes of $H$ forms a partition in $G$.

$|G/K|$ is the order of $G/K$, which is the same as the cardinal or size of $G/K$.

$G/K$ is the set of all lateral classes of $K \le G$. When $K \lhd G$ then $G/K$ is a group.

---

This is from a homework.

I guess I can assume $G$ is finite. If that is the case, I know that $|G/K| = |G|/|K|$

but also, I guess I have to use the next theorem : let $G$ be a group (not neccesarily finite), and $H,K \le G$ then $|HK| = [H : H\cap K] |K|$. If $G$ is finite then $|HK||H \cap K| = |H||K|$

Comment: Don't ask a "no clue" question - see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions).

Comment: Hint: mod out by $K$; then you have a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4420954/742).